# Inconsistency in MS Teams graph api - GET channels

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In the response of GET - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels?$filter=membershipType](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam_id%7D/channels?$filter=membershipType) eq 'private'.

I am getting channels which are not visible in the Teams app interface.
e.g.

{"id": "",
"createdDateTime": "",
"displayName": "testingteam",
"description": null,
"isFavoriteByDefault": null,
"email": null,
"webUrl": null,
"membershipType": "private"
},

Is there any key using which i can differentiate these forbidden channels from the valid ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not able to repro this issue. The graph api returned correct response. Can you check if all webURL part for all such teams you are getting is null. If yes you can add filter ($filter=webUrl ne null).